# Memory usage in a foreach loop C#

Tags: c#, memory, loops, c#-4.0, foreach

I have a foreach loop

```
var axsEntities = GetAxsEntitiesForInvoicing(adapter)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.AccountUsingAccountIdToAccountId);

foreach(var gbAccount in axsEntities)
{
    int i = gbAccount.count(); 
}
```

Now when i run this without the loop it runs fine, but with the loop it uses way too much memory, 3 gigabytes in this case. What could be the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: what is `GetAxsEntitiesForInvoicing`?

Comment: It gets a Ienum of entities(classes that represent a db row data) the row is linked to an account which is what i need to group by. But as soon as i group by the memory goes through the roof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the loop, nothing is really happening.

`axsEntities` is just an IEnumerable with deferred execution.
Creating it is always cheap. Only when Iterating over it (the `foreach`) things are being fetched and computed.

So you just might have very many elements, or `.count()` uses a lot of memory.

Comment: SO the GroupBy has to create the groups in emmory? ;) That CAN be memory intensive, especially if the IEnumerable is "slowly loading them from a database" and the GroupBy materializes everything in memory. IENumerable = crappy source, should be IQueryable.

Comment: TomTom: IQueryable derives from IEnumerable, both are deferred.

Comment: Ah, no. IEnumerable is not deferred in that an IEnumerabl source xcan not get the group by and forward it to the database for example for efficient SQL It has to deliver all the data piece by piece to fullfill the enumeration. Table scan instead of server side group by, so to say.

Answer (score 0):

We'd have to see what type axsEntitie is to be sure, but I'm guessing it is a IQueryable? If so, without the for loop you aren't actually doing *anything* on that set. With the for loop you're actually iterating the result set.

Comment: In that method i say .ToArray() to ensure that the entities are loaded this is not causing the memory usage. Only once the groupby is applied does the memory go through the roof

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is probably lazy evaluated. Try a simple

```
var test = axsEntities.ToList();
```

to see if that also uses a lot of memory.

Comment: Yup the grouping screws it up

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely is NOT the forreach loop, but the GroupBy logic that is delay executed in the loop.

Unless the GetAxyEntitiesForInvoicing method is IQueryable and does not return all entities, the grouping has to happen in memory.

Comment: Could you suggest a better way to do it? The getaxsentitiesforinvoicing returns a IEnumerable

Comment: Rewrite the method to be compatible with LINQ and expose IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

What about `gbAccount.count();` inside a foreach loop? This might not be a good idea. I would first check to see if this is responsible for using the precious memory. My advice is that **you could come up with a more specialized query** e.g. `GetAccountsCountForGroupedAxsEntitiesForInvoicingByAccountUsingAccountIdToAccountIdWithSauce`, this sounds like a really nice name to me.

Peace